# Validate DateTime in Business Logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a field where the user enters a time (HH:MM), and i validate the value on the client-side. Now i want to validate the value in the business logic also. How can i accomplish this?

The value entered should have a semicolon in it like "01:23". My code so far, i tried with tryparse but can't really get it! I dont need to use TryParse, it could be anything.

```
public TimeSpan Speltid
{
    get
    {
        return this._speltid;
    }
    set
    {
        if(!(DateTime.TryParse(value, out ???))
        {
            //Error - Must have a value
        }

        this._speltid = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the `Set` accessor `value` would be a `TimeSpan`, not a string, so `TryParse` is not valid there.

Comment: Validating a TimeSpan property doesn't make sense, it can only be a 'Time Span' a measure of elapsed time. Are you sure this is not a string property?

Answer (score 0):

Use build-in Validators http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kh55542.aspx. They can perform both - client- and server- side validation. RegularExpression validator fully suitable for your task.

If you want to use same validation on BL - develop CustomValidator with RegEx inside and call from BL as well.

For ​hh:mm:ss:

```
bool isOK = Regex.IsMatch(timeTextBox.Text, @"[0-2][0-9]\:[0-6][0-9]\:[0-5][0-9]");
```

Comment: I know, i use that, but i want to validate in business logic also for extra secutiry.

Comment: Ok, but the problem is that i am getting this DateTime value from a database, an Regex.IsMatch takes a string argument. Is it possible to validate datetime in some way? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Confused ) You said that you're validating user input ) why database?)